# Declaring a static private array member

Tags: c++, arrays, static, mingw

My `foo` class needs a static C++ `array` as a private member that I eventually declared this way :

```
class Foo : public Bar {

private:

    constexpr static array<int, 18> rouges = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36};
    // ...
}
```

but the compiler throws

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
error: too many initializers for 'const std::array<int, 18u>'
```

Funny thing my array size is exactly 18 elements here and if I declare it `array<int, 500>` I still get the `too many initializers` error. As for the brace-enclosed initializer error, I don't understand what the compiler expects to read.

I documented myself by looking into *Stroustrup's A Tour of C++* (11.3.1 `array`) but I don't see how he did it differently that I did. Alternatively, removing the `constexpr static` keywords doesn't get rid of the errors.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  [I'm not getting any errors](http://ideone.com/TvfeqI).

Comment: Mingw with the C++11 flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one more pair of braces

```
constexpr static array<int, 18> rouges = { { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 } };
    // ...
```

In fact there are two aggregates one of which is ecnlosed in other.

The initialization  of std;:array is defined like (23.3.2.1 Class template array overview)

> 2 An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the
>   syntax array a = { **initializer-list** }; where
>   initializer-list is a comma-separated list of up to N elements whose
>   types are convertible to T.

And (8.5.1 Aggregates)

> 11 Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows. **If the
>   initializer-list begins with a left brace**, then the succeeding
>   comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the members of
>   a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more
>   initializer-clauses than members.

Comment: Well that worked but... why ?! Can you please elaborate ? All I do see here in a 1-dimensionnal list of ints.

Comment: I am confused because *Stroustrup's A Tour of C++* (11.3.1 `array`) defines it : `array<int,3> a1 = {1,2,3}`. @DeepBlackDwarf thanks for the link. I guess then that the error is compiler dependant then ? I did not get a warning but a real error at my attempt.

Comment: @PinkTurtle  I think that the C++ Standard could be more clear relative to this question.

Comment: @PinkTurtle possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985687/brace-elision-in-stdarray-initialization