# How to initialize std::array in class definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

Since C++11, it is possible to initialize member variables in class definitions:

```
class Foo {
   int i = 3;
}
```

I know I can initialize an std::array like this:

```
std::array<float, 3> phis = {1, 2, 3};
```

How can I do this in a class definition? The following code gives an error:

```
class Foo {
    std::array<float, 3> phis = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

GCC 4.9.1:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer 
std::array<float, 3> phis = {1, 2, 3};
                                     ^ error: too many initializers for 'std::array<float, 3ul>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more set of braces, which is non-intuitive.

```
std::array<float, 3> phis = {{1, 2, 3}};
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why you can say `std::array<float, 3> phis = {1, 2, 3};` outside of a class definition. I would have expected brace elision to apply here too (but I'm usually wrong about this one.)

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you are correct as far as the standard is concerned, see the comments in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists). You *should* be able to use a single set of braces, it is an issue with GCC that is being addressed (AFAIK)