# Excess elements in struct initializer when nested std::array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting `Excess elements in struct initializer` on the `return` line of the following:

```
using triangleColor = std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 3>;

triangleColor colorBlend(TriangleColorBlend c){
    switch (c) {
        case TriangleColorBlend::white:
            return {{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0},{0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0},{0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0}};
            break;

        ... // other cases
    }
}
```

I was hoping the curly-brace literal would work in the nested fashion, as it works fine if I do this with just a single std::array, not nested.

Is the above simply not possible, and why not?

Note, the suggested duplicate doesn't really address the odd behavior of std::array in a nested situation.

Comment: Please take any discussion about the appropriateness of this question to [the meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315498/do-questions-about-code-oddities-need-a-mcve), but the OP is right: a question asking about how to do something does not necessarily require an MCVE for it to stay open. I'll say more in meta.  Shog9 [talked about this in this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306368/should-a-howto-question-about-launching-c-threads-be-closed-for-lacking-an-mcv).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Retracted now. You're right I've been arguing about that earlier, and been proved wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
triangleColor colorBlend(TriangleColorBlend c) {
    switch (c) {
    case TriangleColorBlend::white:
        return {{
            {{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }},
            {{ 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f }},
            {{ 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f }}
        }};
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument("c");
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0604fdf6e98fe4a)</kbd>

There were two issues with your code:

1. You were lacking braces for the inner arrays.
2. As noted by @Praetorian, `colorBlend` had no return value for the default case.

Comment: This seems like a work around. The important question is why does the OP's code not work?

Comment: @RSahu : This is not a workaround, it is the corrected code.

Comment: This indeed solved the problem, many thanks. I was missing the extra braces. I thought in C++14 they were no longer necessary, but I might have misunderstood that detail.s Thanks!

Comment: @johnbakers : In this case they can be elided for the inner arrays ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/107f3902b02a771f)), but the outer array requires both.

Comment: @ildjarn, it seemed to me to be a workaround since there was no explanation of whey the OP's code didn't work. I understand now why it isn't a work around.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a set of brackets.

```
return {{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0},{0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0},{0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0}};
```

Should be

```
return {{{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0},{0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0},{0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0}}};
```

You can see it working in this [minimal example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9acbc722cc7b9445)

Answer (score 3):

Another work around:

```
triangleColor colorBlend(TriangleColorBlend c){
   using t1 = std::array<float, 4>;
   switch (c) {
      case TriangleColorBlend::white:
         return {t1{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0},t1{0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0},t1{0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0}};
         break;

      default:
         break;
   }
   return triangleColor{};
}
```

The answer to the question of why

```
        return {{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0},{0.7,0.7,0.7,1.0},{0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0}};
```

does not work can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192275/434551:

> `std::array` is an aggregate by the rules of C++11, and therefore it can be created by aggregate initialization. To aggregate initialize the array inside the struct, you need a second set of curly braces.