# Constructor of a templated vector(math kind)

Tags: c++

For a small software renderer project I want to work on I'd need different types of vectors so I thought I'd template them up.

```
template<typename T, size_t dim> struct Vector {
  std::array<T, dim> data;

  Vector(){
    data = { 0 };
  }
}
```

This works nice with empty vectors like:

```
Vector<int, 3> v;
```

But how can I create a constructor that would accept a sytax like this:

```
Vector<int, 3> v(1, 2, 3);
```

Thought an std::initializer_list could work like this:

```
Vector(std::initializer_list<T> values){
  data = values;
}
Vector<int, 3> v({1, 2, 3});
```

But the compiler says there's no acceptable conversion between `std::array` and `std::initializer_list` and the `({1, 2, 3})` syntax looks kinda clunky too.

Comment: Write a constructor from `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists

Comment: You can take `std::array<T, dim>` as parameter constructor instead of `std::initializer_list`, So you have the size guaranty.

Comment: @Jarod42 That actually works with the ({}) syntax. On a side question: does this creating/passing an std::array<T, dim> have any serious performace overhead? I'll be throwing in/out/around these vectors quite a bit i feel.

Comment: With correct implementation, you will have `dim` `move` (which is copy for `int`/`float`). `std::initializer` would force the copy. And passing directly by arguments would also require move/copy. So I don't see overhead against the alternatives. If you want a `Vector` cheaper to move, `std::vector` might be an alternative to `std::array` (for the member).

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have a constructor from `initializer_list`, as I've just learned (that sucks). But yes, you can pass an `std::array` instead an init that from aggregate (same curly braces syntax, different semantics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with `std::initializer_list`, but it will with `std::array` proxy:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t dim> struct Vector {
  std::array<T, dim> data;

  Vector(){
    data = { 0 };
  }

  Vector(std::array<T, dim> initial_values) : data(initial_values) {}

};

int main() {
    Vector<int, 3> v({1, 2, 3});
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example how to call it? Cant compile it with either v(1, 2, 3) or v({1, 2, 3}).

Comment: Not as good,than it should be, clang warns about missing brace: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ae2b27afaa297f4). (but if you add them, then you have ambiguous call :-/ [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c09233b3cfb3adf0)). You can still use brace syntax constructor instead of parents, but it seems ugly to me [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac30ebf5c3eaf531).

Answer (score 5):

You can use variadic template:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
Vector(Ts&&... args) : data{{std::forward<Ts>(args)...}}
{}
```

With potentially some SFINAE to restrict this constructor to good number of args, and args convertible to T.

Comment: With a c++14 compliant compiler one `{}` should be enough, right?

Comment: @Bob__: `std::array` is a strange beast.... with only `data{args...}`, compiler allows it but clang warns about missing brace (-Wmissing-braces).