# How to initialize an std::array of strings?

Tags: c++, stdstring, stdarray, list-initialization

I have an `std::array<std::string, 4>` that I want to use to hold path names for text files that I want to read into the program. So far, I declare the array, and then I assign each `std::string` object the value.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
using std::array;
using std::string;
...
array<string, 4> path_names;
path_names.at(0) = "../data/book.txt";
path_names.at(0) = "../data/film.txt";
path_names.at(0) = "../data/video.txt";
path_names.at(0) = "../data/periodic.txt";
```

I am using this approach because I know in advance that there are exactly 4 elements in the array, the size of the array will not change, and each path name is hard coded and also cannot change.

I want to declare and initialize the array and all its elements in just one step. For example, this is how I would declare an initialize an array of `int`s:

```
array<int, 10> ia2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};  // list initialization
```

How would I do the same but for `std::string`? Creating these strings would involve calling the constructor. It's not as simple as just list-initializing a bunch of `int`s. How to do that?

Comment: Did you try to use string literals instead of numbers in the initializer?

Comment: It didn't occur to me that would work. I'll try that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using std::array with initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192185/608639)

Comment: `at` does range checking - obsolete if you are sure that indices are in range (which applies in given case), so prefer index operator `[]`...

Comment: @Aconcagua Is the index operator `[]` more efficient that `at`? Does `at` do a runtime check?

Comment: @Galaxy Yes and yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Using string literals in list initialization

`array<string, 4> path_names = {"../data/book.txt", "../data/film.txt", "../data/video.txt", "../data/periodic.txt"};`

2. Assigning path names to strings and using the strings in initialization.

`string s1 = "../data/book.txt";`
`string s2 = "../data/film.txt";`
`string s3 = "../data/video.txt";`
`string s4 = "../data/periodic.txt";`
`array<string, 4> path_names = {s1, s2, s3, s4};`

And if you want to avoid copies here, you can use `std::move`:

```
array<string, 4> path_names = {std::move(s1), std::move(s2), std::move(s3), std::move(s4)};
```

Comment: Second variant doesn't look any better to me than the one in the question; at least, I'd move the strings instead of copying (`std::move(sN)`)...

Comment: Updated the answer suggesting `std::move` as well.