# Initialize a C++ struct like an array of unknown bound at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I can write this and it works perfectly fine:

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;
  std::string s;
};

const Foo foo[] = {
  { 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
  { 23 /*initializing only the first member, 's' gets the default value*/ }
};
```

What I want to do is to have a struct wrapping the array so I can add methods to it:

```
template<typename V1, typename V2, size_t Count>
struct Map
{
  std::array<std::pair<V1, V2>, Count> mappings;
  //or
  //std::pair<V1, V2> mappings[Count];

  V1 operator()(const V2&) const;
  V2 operator()(const V1&) const;
};
```

And I want to initialize it as an array of unknown bound like this:

```
constexpr Map<int, std::string_view, /*???*/> = {
  { 42, "the answer to the ultimate question" },
  { 23, "some other stuff" },
  { /*...*/ }
};
```

But then a problem arises that you need to specify the `Count` template parameter which I don't want to do, I want it to work like in the array case.

I thought that a function returning such object would do the trick, like this:

```
template<typename V1, typename V2, typename... Args>
constexpr auto makeMap(Args... args)
{
  return Map<V1, V2, sizeof...(Args)>{ args... };
}
```

which then allows to use it like this:

```
using Item = std::pair<int, std::string_view>;

constexpr auto map = makeMap<int, std::string_view>(
  Item{ 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
  Item{ 23, "some other stuff" }
);
```

But if you omit the `Item` type, then template instantiation can not deduce argument types, which prohibits the usage that I originally wanted:

```
constexpr auto map = makeMap<int, std::string_view>(
  { 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
  { 23, "some other stuff" }
);
```

Currently I consider it impossible, but wanted to ask anyway in case I'm missing something.

While researching this, I found [a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1219r0.html) which enables precisely what I want.

Anyways, I would love to get any ideas.

Comment: You add a ctor that takes as input an std::array<std::pair<V1,V2>> so then you could initialize the array with an initializer list

Comment: @Claudiu Guiman, `std::array<Whatever, Count>` will not be able to deduce `Count` from an initializer list. This:
```C++
template<size_t Count>
void test(std::array<int, Count>) {}

int main()
{
  test({1,2,3});
}
```
gives
```
prog.cc:45:3: error: no matching function for call to 'test'
  test({1,2,3});
  ^~~~
prog.cc:41:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Count'
void test(std::array<int, Count>) {}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right - for some weird reason I got it confused with std::vector.
Btw, I know it's not what you asked, but maybe you can use std::vector instead of array?

Comment: @Claudiu Guiman, for runtime initialization — sure. But I want it to work for initialization at compile time using `constexpr`. Though `std::initializer_list` has all members `constexpr`'d in C++17, including `size()`, I couldn't figure out how to make it work to define the `Count` template parameter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists

You can initialize a std::array with two sets of curly braces: std::array<std::string, 2> strings = {{ "a", "b" }};

Comment: @Claudiu Guiman, sure, but the problem is to _not_ specify size and have it be figured out from the number of items in the initializer list.

Comment: Is `Count` arbitrary, or does it have an upper bound ? then  just have to generate N overloads `template<typename V1, typename V2>
constexpr auto makeMap(non_deducible_t<std::pair<V1, V2>> p1, non_deducible_t<std::pair<V1, V2>> p2)`.

Comment: I think your problem could be simplified down to being able to [make this compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1709652587f35e3e).

Comment: @Jarod42, your suggestion will work. Though I think it's better to have just arrays with mappings and have free functions to work with instances of such mapping arrays like this: ```template<typename Mapping, typename Count> auto map(Mapping (&mappings)[Count], T value)```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the proposed [`to_array`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0325r3.html):

```
template<typename V1, typename V2, size_t N>
constexpr auto makeMap(std::pair<V1, V2> const (&a)[N])
{
  return Map<V1, V2, N>{ to_array<std::pair<V1, V2>>(a) };
}

constexpr auto map = makeMap<int, std::string_view>({
  { 42, "the answer to the ultimate question" },
  { 23, "some other stuff" },
  { /*...*/ }
});
```

If your compiler supports library fundamentals TS v2, you can find an implementation of `to_array` in header `<experimental/array>`, inside namespace `std::experimental`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me in this form:
```template<typename V1, typename V2, size_t Count>
constexpr auto makeMap2(std::pair<V1, V2>(&&a)[Count])
{
  return Map<V1, V2, Count>{ to_array(a) };
}
```
Great insight! On monday it goes to production!

Answer (score 2):

Following the Jarod42's suggestion, in a recursive way, I propose a recursive `MakeMyMap` struct, with a `static` `func()` in it that receive a sequence of `std::pair<T1, T2>` arguments [observe: 42 is the default upper bound for the number of `std::pair` arguments].

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t Dim>
struct MyMap
 {
   std::array<std::pair<T1, T2>, Dim> map;
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getTheType = T;

template <typename, typename, typename = std::make_index_sequence<42u>>
struct MakeMyMap;

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>
 {
   using MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>::func;

   static auto func (getTheType<std::pair<T1, T2>, Is> const & ... ps)
    { return MyMap<T1, T2, sizeof...(Is)>{ { { ps... } } }; }
 };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<>>
 {
   static auto func ()
    { return MyMap<T1, T2, 0u>{ }; }
 };
```

So you can write

```
   auto map = MakeMyMap<int, std::string>::func(
      { 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
      { 23, "some other stuff" }
      );
```

The following is a full compiling (C++14 is enough) example

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t Dim>
struct MyMap
 {
   std::array<std::pair<T1, T2>, Dim> map;
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getTheType = T;

template <typename, typename, typename = std::make_index_sequence<42u>>
struct MakeMyMap;

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>
 {
   using MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>>::func;

   static auto func (getTheType<std::pair<T1, T2>, Is> const & ... ps)
    { return MyMap<T1, T2, sizeof...(Is)>{ { { ps... } } }; }
 };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<>>
 {
   static auto func ()
    { return MyMap<T1, T2, 0u>{ }; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   auto map = MakeMyMap<int, std::string>::func(
      { 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
      { 23, "some other stuff" }
      );

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(map),
                               MyMap<int, std::string, 2u>>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Using C++17, you can use `std::string_view` instead of `std::string`, you can define `constexpr` the `func()` functions so `map` can be `constexpr`

```
   constexpr auto map = MakeMyMap<int, std::string_view>::func(
      { 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
      { 23, "some other stuff" }
      );
```

and you can also verify that

```
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(map),
                               MyMap<int, std::string_view, 2u> const>::value, "!" );
```

Using the new C++17 variadic `using`, you can avoid recursion at all rewiting `MakeMyMap` as follows

```
template <typename, typename, typename = std::make_index_sequence<42u>>
struct MakeMyMap;

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public MMM_helper<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<Is>>...
 { using MMM_helper<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<Is>>::func...; };
```

where `MMM_helper` (Make My Map helper) is defined as follows

```
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct MMM_helper;

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MMM_helper<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static constexpr auto func (getTheType<std::pair<T1, T2>, Is> const & ... ps)
    { return MyMap<T1, T2, sizeof...(Is)>{ { { ps... } } }; }
 };
```

The following is a full C++17, not-recursive, example

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t Dim>
struct MyMap
 {
   std::array<std::pair<T1, T2>, Dim> map;
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getTheType = T;

template <typename, typename, typename>
struct MMM_helper;

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MMM_helper<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static constexpr auto func (getTheType<std::pair<T1, T2>, Is> const & ... ps)
    { return MyMap<T1, T2, sizeof...(Is)>{ { { ps... } } }; }
 };

template <typename, typename, typename = std::make_index_sequence<42u>>
struct MakeMyMap;

template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MakeMyMap<T1, T2, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public MMM_helper<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<Is>>...
 { using MMM_helper<T1, T2, std::make_index_sequence<Is>>::func...; };

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto map = MakeMyMap<int, std::string_view>::func(
      { 42, "the answer to the ultimate questions" },
      { 23, "some other stuff" }
      );

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(map),
                               MyMap<int, std::string_view, 2u> const>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Interesting idea, though it is limited to 42 parameters (or a prederemined number).

Comment: @paul - unfortunately you're right: an upper limit is requested. I've improved the answer to show a not-recursive (C++17 only) solution. In the not-recursive way, you can avoid the template recursion limit that can be low. But the upper limit requirement remain.