# Declaring arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl

I am new to C++ and currently learning it with a book by myself. This book seems to say that there are several kinds of arrays depending on how you declare it. I guess the difference between dynamic arrays and static arrays are clear to me. But I do not understand the difference between the STL `std::array` class and a static array.

An STL `std::array` variable is declared as:

```
std::array < int, arraySize > array1;
```

Whereas a static array variable is declared as:

```
int array1[arraySize];
```

Is there a fundamental difference between the two? Or is it just syntax and the two are basically the same?

Comment: No difference, just a matter of syntax and I believe that was only available C++ 11 and above However notice that the STL declaration gives you a big toolbox of functions and iterators you can use on your array, as the other one you generally would have to make built in functions yourself to do the trivial things.: Check: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::array vs array performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263303/stdarray-vs-array-performance)

Comment: There will be a big difference when you start passing `std::array<>` to functions as opposed to built-in arrays.  A `std::array` knows its own size, a built-in array doesn't as it decays to a pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can actually pass a C-style array by reference, in which case the size will be known.

Comment: Off topic minor nag: just call it `std::array`. STL was absorbed into the standard decades ago and `array` came much later.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is just a light wrapper around a C-style array, with some additional nice interface member functions (like `begin`, `end` etc) and `typedef`s, roughly defined as

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class array
{
public:
    T _arr[N];
    T& operator[](size_t);
    const T& operator[](size_t) const;
    // other member functions and typedefs
}
```

One fundamental difference though is that the former can be passed by value, whereas for the latter you only pass a pointer to its first element or you can pass it by reference, but you cannot copy it into the function (except via a `std::copy` or manually).

A common mistake is to assume that every time you pass a C-style array to a function you lose its size due to the array decaying to a pointer. This is not always true. If you pass it by reference, you can recover its size, as there is no decay in this case:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t N>
void f(T (&arr)[N]) // the type of arr is T(&)[N], not T*
{
    std::cout << "I'm an array of size " << N;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    f(arr); // outputs its size, there is no decay happening
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6fe008b5ad022c7)

Comment: You can pass C-style array by reference or by a pointer to the array itself.

Comment: @SergeyA I think I was a bit unclear, edited. The thing is that you definitely cannot pass it by value.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference between these two is an important one.

Besides the nice methods the STL gives you, when passing a `std::array` to a function, there is no decay. Meaning, when you receive the `std::array` in the function, it is still a `std::array`, but when you pass an `int[]` array to a function, it effectively decays to an `int*` pointer and the size of the array is lost.

This difference is a major one. Once you lose the array size, the code is now prone to a lot of bugs, as you have to keep track of the array size manually.  `sizeof()` returns the size of a pointer type instead of the number of elements in the array. This forces you to manually keep track of the array size using interfaces like `process(int *array, int size)`. This is an ok solution, but prone to errors.

See the guidelines by Bjarne Stroustroup:

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rp-run-time

That can be avoided with a better data type, which `std::array` is designed for, among many other STL classes.

As a side note, unless there's a strong reason to use a fixed size array, `std::vector` may be a better choice as a contiguous memory data structure.

Answer (score 7):

`std::array` and C-style arrays are similar:

- They both store a contiguous sequence of objects
- They are both aggregate types and can therefore be initialized using [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)
- Their size is known at compile time
- They do not use dynamic memory allocation

An important advantage of `std::array` is that it can be passed by value and doesn't implicitly decay to a pointer like a C-style array does.

Answer (score 5):

In both cases, the array is created on the stack.

However, the STL's `std::array` class template offers some advantages over the "raw" C-like array syntax of your second case:

> ```
> int array1[arraySize];
> ```

For example, with `std::array` you have a typical STL interface, with methods like `size` (which you can use to query the array's element count), `front`, `back`, `at`, etc.

You can find more details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: "*In both cases, the array is created on the stack*" - unless it is a member of a struct/class that is allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a fundamental difference between the two? or is it just syntax and the two are basically the same?

There's a number of differences for a raw c-style array (*built-in array*) vs. the [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

As you can see from the reference documentation there's a number of operations available that aren't with a raw array:

E.g.: Element access

```
at()
front()
back()
data()
```

The underlying data type of the `std::array` is still a raw array, but garnished with *"syntactic sugar"* (if that should be your concern).

Answer (score 2):

The key differences of `std::array<>` and a C-style array is that the former is a class that wraps around the latter.  The class has `begin()` and `end()` methods that allow `std::array` objects to be easily passed in as parameters to STL algorithms that expect iterators (Note that C-style arrays can too via non member `std::begin`/`std::end` methods).  The first points to the beginning of the array and the second points to one element beyond its end.  You see this pattern with other STL containers, such as `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::set`, etc.

What's also nice about the STL `std::array` is that it has a `size()` method that lets you get the element count. To get the element count of a C-style array, you'll have to write `sizeof(cArray)/sizeof(cArray[0])`, so doesn't `stlArray.size()` looks much more readable?

You can get full reference here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: Non-member `begin` and `end` work just fine with C-style arrays.   With these other improvements (shift to non-member templates) nothing you say is right: arrays can be handled by algorithms with requiring the wrapper to do so.  Arrays have *always* had iterators; making them just like pointers was a founding principle.

Comment: Added your note about non member begin/end.

Comment: «To get the element count of a C-style array, you'll have to write » yuck, and no you don’t. The template shown in vsoftco’s answer illustrates how N is deduced as a template argument. Or just use `end(a)-begin(a)` but why do you need to do that when you *should* be passing the iterators or a “range”. A C array **is** a perfectly good range: the wrapper of array is not needed for any of these reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should prefer `std::array<T, size> array1;` over `T array2[size];`, althoug the underlying structure is identical.

The main reason for that is that `std::array` always knows its size. You can call its [size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) method to get the size. Whereas when you use a C-style array (i.e. what you called "built-in array") you always have to pass the size around to functions that work with that array. If you get that wrong somehow, you could cause buffer overflows and the function tries to read from/write to memory that does not belong to the array anymore. This cannot happen with `std::array`, because the size is always clear.

Comment: In C++ there is no need to always pass the size around, even for C-style arrays. You can pass the array by reference via a template function and recover its size.

Answer (score 1):

IMO,

- Pros: It’s efficient, in that it doesn’t use any more memory than built-in fixed arrays.
- Cons: `std::array` over a built-in fixed array is a slightly more awkward syntax, and that you have to explicitly specify the array length (the compiler won’t calculate it for you from the initializer).