# How to sort a 2D matrix by last column

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix

How can I sort a 2D matrix by last column using a comparable function instead of using position arrays?

`4 20 15 23 18 9 89 
1 8 23 22 14 18 86 
17 15 13 18 12 15 90 
3 18 8 20 12 5 66`

This is my example of 2D matrix where the last column represents the sum of the elements of row ***i = 1 -> n***. I have to sort the rows in ascending order comparing the elements of the last column.

EDIT!

First code was this one:

```
int main()
{
    int x[101][101],y[101],z[101],n,m;
    int i,I,j,l,Mi=1000001,b=0;
    int s=0;

    cin>>n>>m;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(I=1;I<=m;I++)
            cin>>x[i][I];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        s=0;
        for(I=1;I<=m;I++)
            s=s+x[i][I];
        y[i]=s;
    }
    for(l=1;l<=n;l++)
    {
        Mi=1000001;
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if(y[j]<Mi)
            {
                Mi=y[j];
                b=j;
            }
        z[l]=b;
        y[b]=1000002;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
            cout<<x[z[i]][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But as i said..i used possition arrays which are not the best thing to use because they use a lot of space and I don't want that.
The array is an integer array. I got stuck because I don't know another method that's why I wanted to reach for your help.

Comment: Please show your effort and mention where you got stuck

Comment: What's the actual type of this "matrix"?

Comment: A good question should include what code you have, what research you have done, what 'solutions' you have tried and haven't worked , what problem you are, having what is currently being outputted and what you want to be outputted.  This site is NOT for you to post what you want to happen and then have someone write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - use `std::array<T, size>` instead of C-style square bracket arrays (`T[]`). Usage:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 4> matrix{
        {
                {{4, 20, 15, 23, 18, 9, 89}},
                {{1, 8, 23, 22, 14, 18, 86}},
                {{17, 15, 13, 18, 12, 15, 90}},
                {{3, 18, 8, 20, 12, 5, 66}}
        }
};
```

While the confusing number of parentheses might look bizzare at first, you will quickly forget about it when you realise how powerful of a tool `std::array` is.

Second of all - use standard algorithms. You need to:

- obtain the last element of a given row
- obtain the last element of another row
- define a comparison function that would compare aforementioned elements to effectively be used to compare entire rows
- use that function with standard sorting algorithm: `std::sort`

Proposed solution:

```
std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [](const auto& first_row,
                                           const auto& second_row) {
    return first_row.back() < second_row.back();
});
```

We use a *lambda expression* to define a comparator that will compare two rows. That's all `std::sort` needs - a way to compare two elements of a range it sorts - in this case, we define how to compare two *rows of a matrix* (the common `C++` way is to provide a strict weak ordering using less-than operator - that's why `<` is used to compare last elements or each row. If you wish to reverse the order, simply use `>`. Do not use either `<=` or `>=` though, since they do not provide strict ordering).

Comment: Could you give me some great links/materials related to std::array<T,size>. As you said it's very confusing to move from C-style square bracket arrays to this type.

Comment: @Ryk, I think [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263398/7151494) and maybe [this article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-15-an-introduction-to-stdarray/) may be a good starters. Although, I would advise you to get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/7151494). It'll definitely cover information about it

Comment: Do you have a specific c++ book in mind that could help me?

Comment: @Ryk, read my last link carefully. It is a stellar, in depth explanation of currently available, good C++ books. If you asked me personally, I would recommend Bjarne's Programming Principles and Pracrtice book. After that I highly recommend Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers

Answer (score 1):

Look at this simple example. I suggest to use std::vector to store matrix.
For sorting use std::sort with defined compare lambda (*cmp*).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int C = 5, R = 5;
using row = vector<int>;
using matr = vector<row>;

struct matrix
{
    matr m_matrix;
    matrix(int row, int col)
    {
        m_matrix.resize(row);
        for(auto &a : m_matrix)
            a.resize(col);
    }
    void set(int r, int c, int val)
    {
        m_matrix[r][c] = val;
    }
    void sort()
    {
        auto cmp = [](const row &r1, const row &r2)
        {
            return r1[r1.size() - 1] < r2[r2.size() - 1];
        };
        std::sort(m_matrix.begin(), m_matrix.end(), cmp);
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(auto &a : m_matrix)
        {
            for(auto v : a)
                cout << v << "  ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};


void fill_matrix(matrix &m)
{
    int cntr = 15;
    for(int i = 0;i < C;i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0;j < R - 1;j++)
        {
            int value = 10 + (cntr++) % 20;
            m.set(i, j, value);
            sum += value;
        }
        m.set(i, R - 1, sum);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    matrix m(5, 5);
    fill_matrix(m);    
    m.print();
    cout << endl;
    m.sort();
    m.print();
}
```

Results:

[image]