# What’s the difference between "array<>" and “[]” when declaring a C++ array?

Tags: c++, c++11

What's the real difference between declaring an array like this:

```
 array<int, 10> arr;
```

and

```
int arr[10];
```

Comment: The first one is a class defined in the standard library

Comment: If you have `arr1` and `arr2`, declared thusly, `arr1=arr2` will work in one case, and not in the other one. Not the only difference, but the first one to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: That's a question about performance, but answers also describe difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263303/stdarray-vs-array-performance

Comment: The links you both provided were helpful thank you.