# Why are the brackets for a C++ array on the variable and not on the data type?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

I have a Java background and am learning C++. I have a language implementation / syntax decision question.

In Java, array declaration looks like this:

```java
//generally   
type[] variableName;
//concretely
int[] intArray;
```

However, in C++, it looks like this:

```
//generally
type variableName[size];
//concretely
int intArray[5];
```

The Java version makes sense to me, that the brackets should append the datatype. The variable is not an `int`, it's an int array, so we replace the `int` with `int[]`.

In C++, why are the brackets after the variable name?

(Further, C++ seems to agree with this when it comes to pointers. An `int` pointer is `int* intPtr` not `int ptr*`. What am I missing?)

Comment: C declarations in general model the variable's use afterward. You use a pointer via `*p` and you use an array via `arr[i]`. (You can nitpick this because of the relation between those two types, but I hope you see the point.)

Comment: `int[5] arr` might be even wierder because the type of arr might be not `int*`. Besides it doesn't allow `int arr1[5], arr2[10]`.

Comment: I'm out of touch with Java, but doesn't it allow `type variablename[]` as well?

Comment: @cigien - yes, but that syntax is old-fashioned (an early error, following the C/C++ syntax), and 'type[] variable' is preferred nowadays.

Comment: *In c++, why are the brackets after the variable name?* -- Because -- that's the way it is.  C++ is not Java.

Comment: @user16632363  And there you have the explanation. Java designers (while initially supporting C++ syntax) added a syntax that differs from C++.  C++ syntax does not evolve just because Java does.  The more technical reason is that a Java declaration only defines a reference to an array of unspecified size (i.e. sleight-of-hand in providing something like a C++ pointer that may be dynamically initialised to refer to an array of arbitrary size, while claiming to disallow pointers), whereas an array definition in C++ allocates a collection of objects so the size must be known at compile time.

Comment: Re sizing: sure; I was really only considering `int[] foo` versus `int foo[]`.  But yes, the brackets give a 'property' of the type-of-reference.

Comment: My guess is that when Java was developed, heavily inspired by old C++, they modified some syntax like array declaration in a more logical way.

Answer (score 8):

This is a legacy item from `c` which declares it in the same way. I think it is likely just how it was done when `c` was first created. In modern c++ we can avoid using static arrays or pointers. Your example could be written as:

```
std::array<int, 5> intArray;
```

which is both more descriptive and adds lots of benefits. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263398/1294207) for more details.