# a different way of initialising a 2d Array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <array>

array<array<bool,50>,9>coordinates{};
```

I saw this in a code but i didn't understand it, is it a different way to declare a 2d Arrays ?

Comment: What don't you understand about it exactly?

Comment: It seems to be missing the `std::` namespace qualifier.

Comment: to declare an array it should be like this type_name array[][], i don't understand the way it was declared like that

Comment: You can read about the `array` template here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array -- in general, bookmark cppreference.com in your browser, and go there any time you are looking for information on C++.

Comment: std::array has advantages over the c arrays: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263303/stdarray-vs-array-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263303/stdarray-vs-array-performance)

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` is a struct template:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N> struct array;
```

It has several advantages over the *C-style arrays* according to cppreference.com as can be seen below:

> The struct combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its own size, supporting assignment, random access iterators, etc.

Using C-style arrays you have to write it like `bool coordinates[ 9 ][ 50 ] { };`. Here **9** is the number of rows and **50** is the number of columns.

Now let's take a brief look at some code. if you run this code:

```
#include <array>

int main( )
{
    std::array< std::array<bool,50>, 9 > coordinates{ };
    std::cout << sizeof( coordinates ) << '\n';
}
```

You will see:

```
450
```

This means that `coordinates` takes up **9 * 50 == 450** bytes of memory on the stack. This type of array is not dynamically allocated (unlike e.g. `std::vector`).

This:

```
// Prefer the upper one
std::cout << "Pointer to the underlying array: " << coordinates.data( ) << '\n';
std::cout << "Pointer to the underlying array: " << &coordinates << '\n';
```

will result in something similar to this:

```
Pointer to the underlying array: 0x8a651ff540
Pointer to the underlying array: 0x8a651ff540
```

But you should prefer `coordinates.data( )` over `&coordinates[0]`.

And also this:

```
std::cout << "Number of elements: " << coordinates.size( ) << '\n';
std::cout << "Maximum possible number of elements: " << coordinates.max_size( ) << '\n';
```

will give this:

```
Number of elements: 9
Maximum possible number of elements: 9
```

So as can be seen, unlike the conventional **C arrays**, the `std::array` has many member functions that can assist the programmer. Not only that, but it's also **safer** to use. And last but not least, `std::array` is equivalent to C arrays in terms of **performance**.