# STL algorithm and (end of) arrays

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I am new to C++. I was trying using the `accumulate` algorithm from the `numeric` library. Consider the following code segment.

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int b = accumulate(a, a + 3, 0);
```

It turns out that the code segment works and `b` gets assigned 1+2+3+0=6.
If `a` was a `vector<int>` instead of an array, I would call `accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0)`. `a.end()` would point to one past the the end of `a`. In the code segment above, `a + 3` is analogous to `a.end()` in that `a + 3` also points to one past the end of `a`. But with the primitive array type, how does the program know that `a + 3` is pointing at one past the end of some array?

Comment: Pointers to array elements meet the requirements to be a [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), which means that you can use pointers to the beginning and after-the-end of an array the same way you'd use iterators for a container.

Comment: See also [advantages of `std:array` over array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263398/9233560)

Comment: The program doesn't know. It's just comparing like `for (; first != last; ++first) { ... }`.

Comment: Since the standard specifies that array elements are contiguous, the programmer (not the compiler) knows that (for an array with three elements) `a + 3` points one past the end.   Incidentally, you can do `accumulate(begin(a), end(a), 0)` in C++11 and later (not before) whether `a` is a raw array, or any standard container (e.g. `vector`, `array`, `list`, `string`) and let the compiler work out the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The end iterator is merely used for comparison as a stop marker, it does not matter what it really points to as it will never be dereferenced. The `accumulate` function will iterate over all elements in the range [a, a+3[ and stop as soon as it encounters the stop marker.
In the C-style array case, the stop marker will be the element one past the end of the array. This would be the same in the `std::vector` case.