# Assigning pointer from two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ar[2][2] = {1,2,3,4};
    int **p= NULL , i=0, j=0;

    p = ar;             //compiler error. Confused ! Do i need to assign &a or anything. 

    puts("OUT: ");

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d", *(*(ar + i) +  j));
            printf("%2d", *(*(p + i) + j)); /* This is wrong . Compiler error */
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

I want to create a pointer to the 2D array so that instead of `ar` in the `for` loop
i should be able to put `p`. I'm confused. I know other methods of accessing 2d 
elements but i'm confused with this example.

Comment: Should that be `p = ar`? Not `p = a`?

Comment: `int **` and `int [2][2]` are not compatible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515045/passing-two-dimensional-array-via-pointer

Comment: use ....printf("%2d", *(*(p + i) + j)); /*last printf*/

Comment: type of `*p` is `int*`, but there is the address of `a` is an `int` rather than a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you have an array of `int[2]`, while in the second case you have an array of int*.

If you use `sizeof(ar[0])`, it would print `2*sizeof(int)`, while the second would print `sizeof(int*)`.

```
  printf("sizeof(ar)       = %zu\n", sizeof(ar));
  printf("sizeof(ar[0])    = %zu\n", sizeof(ar[0]));
  printf("sizeof(ar[0][0]) = %zu\n", sizeof(ar[0][0]));
  printf("sizeof(p)        = %zu\n", sizeof(p));
  printf("sizeof(*p)       = %zu\n", sizeof(*p));
  printf("sizeof(**p)      = %zu\n", sizeof(**p));
```

Since I tried you code, replaced `p = a` with `p = ar` I only have these errors:

```
$ gcc -Wall foobar.c 
foobar.c: In function ‘main’:
foobar.c:6:3: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
foobar.c:6:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘ar[0]’) [-Wmissing-braces]
foobar.c:12:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
foobar.c:21:7: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

And it fails too:

```
$ ./a.out 
sizeof(ar)       = 16
sizeof(ar[0])    = 8
sizeof(ar[0][0]) = 4
sizeof(p)        = 8
sizeof(*p)       = 8
sizeof(**p)      = 4
OUT: 
Segmentation fault
```

Which is normal, assuming p is not so well defined.

Comment: `%zu` is the correct format specifier for `size_t` since C99.

Comment: What the %z stand for ?

Comment: I amended my answer, removed the u too.

Comment: I re-edited and put the u back in. The format specifier is %zu for decimal unsigned, %zx or %zX for hexadecimal, even %zd works (printing the value as signed) but I'm not completely sure it's endorsed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

`ar[2][2]` will NOT decompose into pointer to pointer `int **p=ar //is wrong`,It will be decomposed into Pointer to first row(if we think in matrix form, which i think its easy),this means in your example your 2-d array consists of 2 rows,Each row has 2 integers(columns).

*Hence `ar` will be decomposed into pointer to 2 integers, Which can be programmatically declared as*

```
int (*p)[2]; //this is pointer to 2 ints
int (*p)[3]; //this is pointer to 3 ints,if your array was declared like this ar[2][3]
```

So in your program you need to change `int **p=NULL` to `int (*p)[2];`

*When we say a pointer to 2 integers,it means that When you add one `(ex:- p+1) for above example` then this will point to the next two integers of 2-d array(which means next row).*

Answer (score 0):

a quote from [comp.lang.c FAQ list, Question 6.18](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html)

> The rule (see question 6.3) by which arrays decay into pointers is not
>   applied recursively. (Once the rule has been applied once, the result
>   is a pointer to which the rule no longer applies.) An array of arrays
>   (i.e. a two-dimensional array in C) decays into a pointer to an array,
>   not a pointer to a pointer.

`int **` and `int [2][2]` are not compatible. you should think of your `ar` array as of an array that holds another arrays. multidimensional arrays allocated on stack are stored in memory continguously. 
statement `int ar[2][2]` will be changed by the compiler to `int (*ar)[2]`. notice the placement of parentheses. this is because of operators precedence:

- `()` operator has higher precendece than `[]` operator
- `[]` operator has higher precedence than `*` operator.

. so if you would omit them, then:

```
int *ar[2];  // ar is an array of length 2 that holds pointers to ints.
int (*ar)[2];  // ar is a pointer to array of length 2 that hold ints.
```

you can resolve your problem by:

- changing `int **p = NULL;` to `int (*p)[2];`
- changing `int ar[2][2]` to `int **ar` and then properly allocate memory for rows and columns using `malloc()`

think of how that 2d array is subscripted. for example, the statement:

```
printf("%2d ", *(*(ar + 1) +  1));  // print the ar[1][1]
```

adds `1` to `ar` pointer, which points to `int [2]`. 8 bytes are added to the address of beginning of array, then after dereference adding `1` will add only 4 bytes, since it refers now to int.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)   
{    
    const int row=4, col=4;
    int ar[row][col] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    int **p= NULL ; 
    int *np =  &ar[0][0];            
    p = &np;

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0 ; j < col; j++)
       {
            printf("address of a[%d][%d] is %x\n",i,j,&ar[i][j]);
            printf("%2d\n", *(*(ar + i) +  j));
            printf("%2d\n", *(*(p)+ i*col  + j));
       }
    }

    _getch();
    exit(0);
}
```

i tried like this, it worked for me.

Comment: I don't think `p` will behave the way you expect it to. If you try to use i.e. `p[1]`, you'll more than likely get a segfault.